# Share OpenGraph activity on Facebook from android APP doesn't work on few devices

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an app similar to the runkeeper where user tracks his activity and shares on facebook. I am testing it on two devices with same API level 23. The sharing works perfectly fine on one of them. For the second device it looks as if Facebook activity is launching and crashing immediately.
Below is my code snippet

```
ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("fb:app_id", getString(R.string.facebook_app_id))
    .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
    .putString("og:title", title)
    .putString("og:url", url)
    .putString("fitness:duration:value", "3600")
    .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
    .putString("fitness:distance:value", String.format("%.2f", distance))
    .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
    .putString("fitness:speed:value", "25")
    .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s");

int i = 0;
for(Location loc: locationArray){
    object.putDouble("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:location:latitude", loc.latitude);
    object.putDouble("fitness:metrics["+i+"]:location:longitude", loc.longitude);
    i++;
}

// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("fitness.walks")
    .putObject("fitness:course", object.build())
    .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();

ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
    shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
}
```

The logcat shows below error

```
01-16 20:32:41.807 1767-3108/? I/ActivityManager: START u0     {act=com.facebook.platform.PLATFORM_ACTIVITY cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] pkg=com.facebook.katana cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity (has extras)} from uid 10337 on display 0
01-16 20:32:41.893 5230-5230/ I/Choreographer: Skipped 946 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-16 20:32:42.094 11818-12203/? V/ConnectivityManager: isActiveNetworkMetered() returns:true
01-16 20:32:42.179 11818-12124/? E/X.0SQ: RuntimeException while executing runnable com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6@841f317 with executor X.0TB@f2c51c6
                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                          at X.0PB.checkArgument(:55122)
                                          at com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.ComposerConfiguration.<init>(:1303891)
                                          at com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.ComposerConfiguration$Builder.a(:1303267)
                                          at X.Gvr.onSuccess(:2406163)
                                          at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(:68028)
                                          at X.0TB.execute(:62606)
                                          at X.03X.a(:10463)
                                          at X.0SQ.executeListener(:61282)
                                          at X.0SQ.complete(:61256)
                                          at X.0SQ.completeWithFuture(:61263)
                                          at X.0SQ.setFuture(:61159)
                                          at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AsyncChainingFuture.a(:310870)
                                          at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$AbstractChainingFuture.run(:247912)
                                          at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$2$1.run(:311624)
                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                          at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(:77498)
                                          at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(:63229)
                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                          at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(:77690)
                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-16 20:32:42.211 1767-1863/? I/LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity,wp,ca,303
01-16 20:32:42.211 1767-1863/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.platform.common.activity.PlatformWrapperActivity: +303ms
01-16 20:32:42.436 2425-2980/? I/NetworkController.MotorolaMobileSignalController(1): MotorolaMobilePhoneStateListener.onDataActivity: Entered: direction=3
```

Any Ideas? TIA

**Edit1**
So, the bug on that particular device suddenly disappeared without any change from our side. So I am pretty much sure Facebook fixed something from their side. But this problem still occurs on few of the devices. I will post the update if needed

Comment: Hi @Saket. I am experiencing the same problem on RemixOS 3.0.207 (Android 6.0.1). Did you ever get any insight on what caused this, or why it "suddenly disappeared"? I'm using Facebook SDK 4.22.1.

Comment: Hi @jules, Its too late to comment but we experienced too many problems with Facebook Open graph so eventually gave up and created our own link and info image to share. 

And I could not figure out the reason behind "sudden disappearance". I still suspect Facebook fixed something from their side.